# set session variable for Hasura on Query in apollo client, currently getting error "missing session variable: "x-hasura-a"

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client, hasura

I'm currently writing a next.js app. I have got a query in apollo graphql, that I want to attach a variable to, in the header of the request. The variable is called x-hasura-a .

Trying to use it like:

```
const variable ='Test'

  const get_query = gql'...'

  const {
    loading,
    error,
    data,
  } = useQuery(
    get_query,
    {
      variables: { asdf: 'asdf' },
    },
    {
      options: {
        context: {
          headers: {
            'x-hasura-a': variable,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  )
```

Does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#context), `context` is a property of the `options` config object.

You already have `variables` defined in there. Just add `context`.

Like so:

```
const variable ='Test'

  const get_query = gql'...'

  const {
    loading,
    error,
    data,
  } = useQuery(
    get_query,
    {
      variables: { asdf: 'asdf' },
      context: {
        headers: {
          'x-hasura-a': variable,
        },
      },
    }
  )
```